# How to train a reinforcement learning agent from raw pixels?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, ai-design, deep-rl

How would you train a reinforcement learning agent from raw pixels?

For example, if you have 3 stacked images to sense motion, then how would you pass them to neural networks to output Q-learning values?

If you pass that batch output, it would be a batch of values, so from here it is impossible to deduce which ones are the true Q-values for that state.

Currently, I am watching a YouTuber: [Machine Learning with Phil](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RfNxXlO6BiA), and he did it very differently. On the 13th minute, he defined a network that outputs a batch of values rather than Q-values for 6 states. In short, he outputs a matrix rather than a vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How would you train a reinforcement learning agent from raw pixels? For example, if you have 3 stacked images to sense motion, then how would you pass them to neural networks to output Q-learning values?

A Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) structure is a standard neural network architecture when working with 2D pixel input in reinforcement learning, and it is the technique used in the original DQN paper (see paragraphs 1 & 3 of Section 4.1 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.5602). CNNs typically take 3-dimensional input, where the first two dimensions are `height` and `width` of your images, and the third is `rgb color`. The technique in the paper was to convert each RGB frame (or image) to greyscale format (so it has only 1 color channel/dimension instead of 3) and instead use the `rgb_color` dimension as a `frames` dimension that is indexed by each stacked frame.

> Currently, I am watching a YouTuber: Machine Learning with Phil, and he did it very differently. On the 13th minute, he defined a network that outputs a batch of values rather than Q-values for 6 states. In short, he outputs a matrix rather than a vector.

Later in the tutorial series, he most likely will discuss the training of the neural network. During training, you need to find the q-values of a batch of sets of stacked frames. Specifically, **each element of the batch is a set of stacked frames**. In other words, a set of stacked frames is treated as a single observation, so a batch of sets of stacked frames is a batch of observations.

To find these q-values, you will perform a forward pass of the batch of observations through the neural network. A forward pass of a single observation (set of stacked frames) through the neural network yields a vector of q-values (one for each action). Thus, a forward pass of a batch of observations (batch of stacked frames) will yield a matrix of q-values (one vector of q-values for each observation (or set of stacked frames)). This technique is used because many standard neural network libraries are designed to **perform a forward pass on a batch of inputs through the neural network much faster than performing a forward pass on each input separately**.